# Flat Rate shipping region code

Tags: magento2, table-rates

I want to implement flat rate shipping for magento 2 in New Zealand

I am unable to find region code list Like Auckland, Wellington, Christchurch and Dunedin etc

Please, anyone, guide me so that I find Region/State code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento does not include regions of New Zealand (and several other countries).

So there are three options:

1.
You can set up your table rates based on post / zip codes

---

> Note: As I had no need of adding additional regions to any version of Magento yet the following two points are not based on "hands-on practice"! Please make sure you keep backups of your system take your time to find the best fitting approach!

---

2.
Or, if this is not sufficient to you you may refer to this article, that explains, how you can add new regions to Magento:

- https://magento2-blog.com/magento-add-regions-to-country/

Basically you have to add your additional region data to the following two tables:

- `directory_country_region`
- `directory_country_region_name`

**Demo** insert SQL's as given on above link:

```
insert into directory_country_region (country_id, code, default_name) values ("NZ", "AU", "Auckland");
insert into directory_country_region (country_id, code, default_name) values ("NZ", "WE", "Wellington");
insert into directory_country_region (country_id, code, default_name) values ("NZ", "CC", "Christchurch");
insert into directory_country_region (country_id, code, default_name) values ("NZ", "DU", "Dunedin");
```

and

```
insert into directory_country_region_name values ("en_US", 507, "Auckland");
insert into directory_country_region_name values ("en_US", 508, "Wellington");
insert into directory_country_region_name values ("en_US", 509, "Christchurch");
insert into directory_country_region_name values ("en_US", 510, "Dunedin");
```

> *Note:* It is generally a bad idea and practice to run insert/update/alter SQL statements directly against your store's database! However, this may at least help you to find the right track on how to approach your issue.

---

3.
https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager - I just found this extension while I was looking for some references. It states that

> This module provides flexibility of managing the regions for each country in your Magento Admin.

and seem to be an interesting hit on this topic.